# Constructing an Eigen::AngleAxisd object from a Eigen::Matrix3d rotation matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, robotics, eigen3, rotational-matrices

I'm trying to control the trajectory of the orientation of an end-effector of a robot, to do so I need to work with axis angle representation.

First I obtain the Rotation matrix (**Rot**) from the actual pose (**Ri**) to the final pose (**Rf**).
And then I build the  Eigen::AngleAxisd object from the rotation matrix.
But when I check the values of the Eigen::AngleAxisd they are not correct.

I have tried to convert back to a matrix representation and print the results from the original Matrix rotation and the rotation extracted from the AxisAngle object. But I get different values.

**The part of the code:**

```
Eigen::Matrix3d Rot = Ri.transpose() * Rf;
Eigen::AngleAxisd ax_rot;
ax_rot.fromRotationMatrix(Rot);

std::cout << "The relative rot before:\n" << Rot << std::endl;
std::cout << "The relative rot after:\n" << ax_rot.matrix() << std::endl;
```

**The output:**

```
The relative rot before:
    0.707107    -0.707107 -1.91864e-17
    0.707107    -0.707107  1.91861e-17
     1.05879e-22        0            1 
The relative rot after:
    0.333333    -0.942809 -2.18354e-17
    0.942809     0.333333  3.74618e-18
     3.74654e-18 -2.18353e-17        1
```

The *The relative rot before:* is correct but the *The relative rot after:* should be the same. Does anybody know how to convert properly from Matrix3d to AxisAngled representation?

Comment: "The relative rot before: is correct" -- did you check the determinant of that matrix? It looks near singular to me (for a rotation matrix, the determinant should be (numerically) equal to 1.0)

Comment: Actually you where right, The way I buid my rotation matrix from euler angles was wrong! Thanks for the help :) @chtz